# Finding stored procedures having execute permission

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I need to list out all the stored procedures that a database user (MYUSER)  has execute permission.

Also, I need to list out which are the stored procedures that the user does NOT have EXECUTE permission - but can read the script of the stored procedure

Is there any SQL statement or helper function for these purpose?

REFERENCE:

1. [Granting execute permission on all stored procedures in a certain database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109581/granting-execute-permission-on-all-stored-procedures-in-a-certain-database)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189802.aspx):

```
select name, 
    has_perms_by_name(name, 'OBJECT', 'EXECUTE') as has_execute,
    has_perms_by_name(name, 'OBJECT', 'VIEW DEFINITION') as has_view_definition
from sys.procedures
```

Comment: I can view the script of the stored procedure using "Script Stored Procedure As"--> "Create To"; but the has_view_definition is coming as "0". How can we correct it?

Comment: Can you run [`SELECT * FROM sys.fn_my_permissions('<procedure>', 'OBJECT')`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176097.aspx) and post here the result?

Comment: BTW, my query does not handle procedures in other schema, not dbo. You can easily fix that yourself.

Answer (score 18):

To check the permission for a different user, use this:

```
use my_db;
EXECUTE AS user = 'my_user'
SELECT SUSER_NAME(), USER_NAME();
select name, 
    has_perms_by_name(name, 'OBJECT', 'EXECUTE') as has_execute

from sys.procedures
where name = 'myprocname';
revert;
```

Works for my SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Works in 2008 R2

Answer (score 10):

The answer from knb doesn't work for me because of missing rights. (a solution for a different user than the current one)

> Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "my user"
>   does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you
>   do not have permission.

This [answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ff9b77a8-7358-4c71-88b1-0e420d7c25ab/list-of-stored-procedures-with-permission-for-executing-for-user?forum=sqlsecurity) shows how to get the list of stored procedures on which a specific database user ('my user') has EXECUTE permission explicitly granted:

```
SELECT [name]
FROM sys.objects obj
INNER JOIN sys.database_permissions dp ON dp.major_id = obj.object_id
WHERE obj.[type] = 'P' -- stored procedure
AND dp.permission_name = 'EXECUTE'
AND dp.state IN ('G', 'W') -- GRANT or GRANT WITH GRANT
AND dp.grantee_principal_id = 
    (SELECT principal_id
    FROM sys.database_principals 
    WHERE [name] = 'my user')
```

I modified it as follows to get the list I need:

```
SELECT [name]
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE [name] NOT IN
    (SELECT [name]
    FROM sys.objects obj
    INNER JOIN sys.database_permissions dp ON dp.major_id = obj.object_id
    WHERE obj.[type] = 'P' -- stored procedure
    AND dp.permission_name = 'EXECUTE'
    AND dp.state IN ('G', 'W') -- GRANT or GRANT WITH GRANT
    AND dp.grantee_principal_id = 
        (SELECT principal_id
        FROM sys.database_principals 
        WHERE [name] = 'my user'))
```

Tested on Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 5):

`HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME`, as used in the context of the script provided in the first answer, will provide the desired result only if you are connected as `"MYUSER"` since this function

> "Evaluates the effective permission of the current user"

Answer (score 3):

Extending on the accepted answer above, in order to check objects outside of the `dbo` schema, use the following statement.

```
  SELECT 
    name,
    HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(name), 'OBJECT', 'EXECUTE') AS has_execute,
    HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(name), 'OBJECT', 'VIEW DEFINITION') AS has_view_definition
  FROM sys.procedures
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to find rights for an SP that was not in [dbo] !