# How to get users who has execute permission for a specific sp in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How do I get all the users/ user groups/ user roles who are having execute permission on a specific stored procedure in MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I think you can start here:
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_builtin_permissions('EX');

Comment: You can find some usefull infromation also here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152329/finding-stored-procedures-having-execute-permission

Comment: No luck @PeterRing , this [SELECT * FROM sys.fn_builtin_permissions('EX')] returns 0 rows :(

Comment: @PeterRing - I executed below query from above given link, but it does not return users, seems it returns current logged in user permissions for SP. select name, 
    has_perms_by_name(name, 'OBJECT', 'EXECUTE') as has_execute,
    has_perms_by_name(name, 'OBJECT', 'VIEW DEFINITION') as has_view_definition
from sys.procedures

Answer (score 1):

Running a profiler trace on SSMS activity reveals that SSMS gathers this data for the stored procedure properties window with the following query, which you could probably customise for your purposes (note that the values for the last two parameters need to be customised to consider the procedure you're interested in):

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
grantee_principal.name AS [Grantee],
CASE grantee_principal.type WHEN ''R'' THEN 3 WHEN ''A'' THEN 4 ELSE 2 END - CASE ''database'' WHEN  ''database'' THEN 0 ELSE 2 END AS [GranteeType]
FROM
sys.all_objects AS sp
INNER JOIN sys.database_permissions AS prmssn ON prmssn.major_id=sp.object_id AND prmssn.minor_id=0 AND prmssn.class=1
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS grantee_principal ON grantee_principal.principal_id = prmssn.grantee_principal_id
WHERE
(sp.type = @_msparam_0 OR sp.type = @_msparam_1 OR sp.type=@_msparam_2)
and(sp.name=@_msparam_3 and SCHEMA_NAME(sp.schema_id)=@_msparam_4)',
N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_2 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_3 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_4 nvarchar(4000)',
@_msparam_0=N'P',@_msparam_1=N'RF',@_msparam_2=N'PC',@_msparam_3=N'~procedure name~',@_msparam_4=N'~procedure schema~'
```

It's probably worth noting that this doesn't include users who implicitly have execute permissions because of high-level role memberships (by virtue of being members of the `sysadmin` server role, for example).

Neither does it expand role memberships into individual users.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query. It will return users and roles with `EXECUTE` permissions on ALL stored procedures and functions. You will have to customize to filter just the object you need.

```
SELECT  
    [UserName] = CASE princ.[type] 
                    WHEN 'S' THEN princ.[name]
                    WHEN 'U' THEN ulogin.[name] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
                 END,
    [UserType] = CASE princ.[type]
                    WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                    WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
                 END,  
    [DatabaseUserName] = princ.[name],       
    [Role] = null,      
    [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],       
    [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],       
    [ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],       
    [ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM    
    --database user
    sys.database_principals princ  
LEFT JOIN
    --Login accounts
    sys.login_token ulogin on princ.[sid] = ulogin.[sid]
LEFT JOIN        
    --Permissions
    sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = princ.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Table columns
    sys.columns col ON col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
LEFT JOIN
    sys.objects obj ON perm.[major_id] = obj.[object_id]
WHERE 
    princ.[type] in ('S','U') AND perm.[permission_name] = 'EXECUTE'
UNION
--List all access provisioned to a sql user or windows user/group through a database or application role
SELECT  
    [UserName] = CASE memberprinc.[type] 
                    WHEN 'S' THEN memberprinc.[name]
                    WHEN 'U' THEN ulogin.[name] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
                 END,
    [UserType] = CASE memberprinc.[type]
                    WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                    WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
                 END, 
    [DatabaseUserName] = memberprinc.[name],   
    [Role] = roleprinc.[name],      
    [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],       
    [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],       
    [ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],   
    [ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM    
    --Role/member associations
    sys.database_role_members members
JOIN
    --Roles
    sys.database_principals roleprinc ON roleprinc.[principal_id] = members.[role_principal_id]
JOIN
    --Role members (database users)
    sys.database_principals memberprinc ON memberprinc.[principal_id] = members.[member_principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Login accounts
    sys.login_token ulogin on memberprinc.[sid] = ulogin.[sid]
LEFT JOIN        
    --Permissions
    sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Table columns
    sys.columns col on col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
LEFT JOIN
    sys.objects obj ON perm.[major_id] = obj.[object_id]
WHERE  perm.[permission_name] = 'EXECUTE' 
UNION
--List all access provisioned to the public role, which everyone gets by default
SELECT  
    [UserName] = '{All Users}',
    [UserType] = '{All Users}', 
    [DatabaseUserName] = '{All Users}',       
    [Role] = roleprinc.[name],      
    [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],       
    [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],       
    [ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],  
    [ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM    
    --Roles
    sys.database_principals roleprinc
LEFT JOIN        
    --Role permissions
    sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Table columns
    sys.columns col on col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]                   
JOIN 
    --All objects   
    sys.objects obj ON obj.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
WHERE
    --Only roles
    roleprinc.[type] = 'R' AND
    --Only public role
    roleprinc.[name] = 'public' AND
    --Only objects of ours, not the MS objects
    obj.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND
    perm.[permission_name] = 'EXECUTE' 
ORDER BY
    princ.[Name],
    OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    col.[name],
    perm.[permission_name],
    perm.[state_desc],
    obj.type_desc--perm.[class_desc]
```